# How to load an aligned word2vec model in Gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a time series dataset. therefore, for each time period I trained a word2vec model and realigned the models.

However, when I try to load the aligned word2vec models as follows I get the below mentioned error.

```
#Load model
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load('model_1970')
```

Error:

```
train_words_pow += wv.vocab[wv.index2word[word_index]].count**power
KeyError: 'ctrx'
```

Is there a way to resolve this error? :)

I have attached a sample trained word2vec model that gives error for testing purposes

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IBbUgeAubr2xzNYLKZgPt34xOEsW92bO/view?usp=sharing

EDIT:
Mention below is the log of my program.

```
2018-11-30 14:23:43,897 : INFO : loading Word2Vec object from model_1970
2018-11-30 14:23:43,961 : INFO : loading wv recursively from model_1970.wv.* with mmap=None
2018-11-30 14:23:43,965 : INFO : loading vectors from model_1970.wv.vectors.npy with mmap=None
2018-11-30 14:23:44,005 : INFO : setting ignored attribute vectors_norm to None
2018-11-30 14:23:44,009 : INFO : loading vocabulary recursively from model_1970.vocabulary.* with mmap=None
2018-11-30 14:23:44,009 : INFO : loading trainables recursively from model_1970.trainables.* with mmap=None
2018-11-30 14:23:44,009 : INFO : loading syn1neg from model_1970.trainables.syn1neg.npy with mmap=None
2018-11-30 14:23:44,053 : INFO : setting ignored attribute cum_table to None
2018-11-30 14:23:44,053 : INFO : loaded model_1970
Reloaded modules: __mp_main__
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-3b9230dacba9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Emi/Desktop/code/word2vec_distance.py', wdir='C:/Users/Emi/Desktop/code')

  File "C:\Users\Emi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Emi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Emi/Desktop/code/word2vec_distance.py", line 26, in <module>
    model_1 = word2vec.Word2Vec.load(word2vec_model_name_1)

  File "C:\Users\Emi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 975, in load
    return super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Emi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 631, in load
    model.vocabulary.make_cum_table(model.wv)  # rebuild cum_table from vocabulary

  File "C:\Users\Emi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1383, in make_cum_table
    train_words_pow += wv.vocab[wv.index2word[word_index]].count**power

KeyError: 'cmnx'
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make one of the models available to test?

Comment: @PedroTorres Thanks a lot for the comment. I am using the following code to align my word2vec models https://gist.github.com/quadrismegistus/09a93e219a6ffc4f216fb85235535faf
  My real models are very big. I will do a test model and attach it soon :)

Comment: @PedroTorres updated the question :)

Comment: Tried it here. It does show the error. It seems like the problem is with the vocabulary dictionary given by wv.vocab. For some reason it does not have all the words

Comment: @PedroTorres I did a modification to the model's vocabulary (i.e aligning the model) using the gensim code in https://gist.github.com/quadrismegistus/09a93e219a6ffc4f216fb85235535faf  Any idea how to resolve this issue? :)

Comment: Where did you get the model. did you train it in gensim? do you have the text version of the file? if you have, you can see if it's in proper format

Comment: As suggested in an answer your earlier question received on the `gensim` discussion list, why do you expect the word in question (here `'ctrx'`) to be present in the `'1970'` model? (That error is an unambiguous indication that it is not.) If the `'1970'` model has been synthesized from multiple models using code not shown, and that synthesis process ('alignment') means `'1970'` only includes words that were in all the constituent models, is that word in all the constituent models? (`'ctrx'` doesn't look like a natural/common word.)

Comment: Also, generally showing the full call-stack that led to the error, and not just the error itself, can help clarify where/why an error is happening. (For example, what files/line-numbers are shown? Did your error specifically happen during `load()`, or in a later step on the loaded model?)

Comment: @gojomo Thanks a lot for your valuable thoughts. I have updated my question with the log I received. Can you please let me know how to fix this? :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I see that the error is occuring during a normal load, where a necessary data structure is rebuilt. My only guess is that the "aligned" process code, which I don't particularly understand, has broken the internal assumptions of the gensim code about the consistency of internal vocabulary structures... creating an essentially-corrupt model that can't be loaded. It may be because that code was written for an older version of gensim & would need to be updated. You could inquire with its author, or others who have been using it, to see if they have updates/workarounds.

Comment: @gojomo Thanks a lot for your valuable thoughts. :)